# Is there any way to run a SSIS Job inside in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, jobs

I want to ask if there are possible ways to execute a SSIS Job in Visual Studio. For Example scenario I'm using asp.net for example i want to extract file i already created an SSIS for the extract file then the User Interface Have date filter to filter want date you want to extract then click Extract file. if the user clicked the extract button so that the SSIS job trigger in the MS SQL. is it possible?

Comment: "SSIS Job in SQL Server" Do you mean you have defined a SQL Agent Job that has a child step which runs an SSIS package? When you say you "want to run the job inside visual studio" what do you mean?

Comment: Are you talking about a button on a web page? The run a package? If so, you can run a package with a SQL statement. This goes above and beyond with it how to... https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6528/execute-ssis-package-from-stored-procedure-in-sql-server/

Comment: Hi @billinkc. I'm using asp.net for example i want to extract file i already created an SSIS for the extract file then the User Interface Have date filter to filter want date you want to extract then click Extract file. if the user clicked the extract button so that the SSIS job trigger in the MS SQL.

Comment: Hi @KeithL I Already edit the question

Comment: My answer remains the same. Execute package via SQL from c# on your asp site.